# Brouwer degree formula premises

Tags: algebraic-topology

We know that the degree of a map $f: S^k \to S^k$ is given by the following formula

$$\text{deg}(f) = \frac{\int_{S^k} f^*(\omega)}{\int_{S^k}\omega}$$

Under what conditions on $f$ is this formula valid?

Comment: The last line here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#Differential_topology , as long as $\omega$ is a volume form (i.e. non-vanishing so that $\int_{S^k} \omega \neq 0$), this formula is valid for any smooth map $f$. In fact, since any continuous map $f$ can be approximated by (i.e. is homotopic to) a smooth map, you can use a smooth approximation to any continuous map to use this formula. Finding this approximation in practice is a whole other question though.

Comment: @OsamaGhani, so it has to be at least continuous, right? It cannot be discontinuous even on a set of measure zero?

Comment: In general the degree of a map doesn't really make sense if the function is discontinuous (at least, not in any sense that I know), so sort of by definition it has to be continuous/smooth.